# Type mismatch with map and flatMap

Tags: scala, types, dictionary

While trying to play with Options in scala I have come across this peculiar problem.

I started off with creating a List[Option[Int]] as follows:

```
scala> List(Some(1),Some(2),None,Some(3))
res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3))
```

Then I tried to map an addition to 1 over the entries of the list in res0 as follows:

```
scala> res0 map (_ + 1)
```

This gave me the error:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              res0 map (_ + 1)
                            ^
```

Then I tried flatMapping an addition over the entries as follows:

```
scala> res0 flatMap (_ + 1)
```

This gave me the same error:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              res0 flatMap (_ + 1)
                                ^
```

But something like `res0.flatMap(r => r)` works just fine with a result of:

```
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Can anybody tell me why adding the entry to 1 would fail for both map and flatMap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two things you tried failed because you are trying to add an `Option` to an `Int`, and that's not possible.

The weird error message happens because Scala assumes, since `Option` doesn't have a `+` method, that you are trying `String` concatenation, but you'd have to either add an `Option` to a `String`, or a `String` to an `Option`, and you are doing neither, hence the error message.

In the last case, you are not trying to add anything, you are simply returning `Option` as is, hence no error message.

Comment: I think sc_ray also got confused because when trying `res0 flatMap (_ + 1)` he probably thought that it is equivalent to `res0.flatten.map(_ + 1)` (which is apparently what he was trying to do) while in fact it is equivalent to `res0.map(_ + 1).flatten`. Maybe `flatMap` should have been called `mapFlat` instead of `flatMap`:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use get to extract the value from `Some[Int]` to `Int` allowing for calculation `value + 1` ie:

```
res0 map{_.getOrElse(0) + 1}
```

As pointed out by @Sepp2k you could alternatively use a `collect` to avoid having a default for `None`

```
res0 collect {case Some(x) => x + 1 }
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to treats `None`s as 0. At least he said nothing to suggest that.

Comment: This is to avoid a `NoSuchElementException` on calling `get` on `None` a verbose alternative would be to use collect to avoid this.

Comment: Two things can't be alternatives to each other if they produce different results.

Comment: In this case it would help unpack `Some(x)` to `x` and it looks good to my eyes(I like the syntax).

Answer (score 1):

To increment all values that are not `None`, you need to map also each `Option` element of the list, like so:

```
scala> res0.map(_.map(_ + 1))
res1: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(2), Some(3), None, Some(4))
```

If you want to filter out the `None`s, you would indeed use a `flatMap`:

```
scala> res0.flatMap(_.map(_ + 1))
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the function given to `flatMap` as well as the function given to `map` take a value of the list's element type - in this case `Option[Int]`. But your function `_ + 1` expects an `Int`, not an `Option[Int]`, so you can't use it as the argument to either `map` or `flatMap` in this case. Further the function given to `flatMap` should return an iterable¹, but your function would return a number.

This will do what you want: `res0 flatMap (_ map (_ + 1))`. Here the function given to `flatMap` takes an `Option[Int]` and returns an `Option[Int]` by calling `map` on the option. `flatMap` then takes the options returned by the function and concatenates them.

¹ Technically a `GenTraversableOnce`.

Answer (score 1):

You try to invoke`e.+(1)` on every element `e` in a `List[Option[Int]]`, but `+` is not a function declared by `Option[_]`. String concatenation, however, would be possible (I assume there is an implicit from `Any` to `String`), but only if the second argument were a string as well (not sure why the implicit whose existence I assumed isn't considered here).

You can overcome this problem by doing working with a default value as suggested by @korefn, or "hide" the differentiation between `Some(x)` and `None` in another invocation of `map`, namely by

```
map(_.map(_ + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

They are failing because the types are wrong and the compiler correctly states it as such.

The map case fails because `map` expects a function `A => B`. In your code, `A => B` is really `Int => Int` which will not work because calling `map` on your list means that `A` is actually  `Option[Int]`.

Furthermore, `flatMap` expects a function of the form `A => F[B]`. So you will get your answer if you did `res0 flatMap { o => o map { a => a + 1 } }`. This basically is the expansion of:

```
for {
  element <- res0 // o above
  value <- element // a above
} yield value + 1
```